# Publish web app error Copying file Symbols

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to publish a website that I have never published before and am getting the following error. I've never seen this before has anyone come across this?

> Copying file
>   Symbols\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb\78C7E2CECAEA49F8BC4DFBDECC5199881\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb
>   to
>   C:\Users\tcarlson\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\CRMDashboard--898440104\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Symbols\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb\78C7E2CECAEA49F8BC4DFBDECC5199881\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb
>   failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: I understand that. the path I have in is \\USASPDEV02\Inetserv\Dashboard Published which isn't to many characters. I'm not sure what I need to change.

Comment: It looks to me like it's trying to copy it to a folder that starts with `C:\Users\tcarlson\AppData\Local....` and it's really really long. Have you double checked your publish settings? Something isn't set right.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the issue. Under Publish\Settings\File Publish Options the Precompile during publishing was causing the issue.